# Filtering an Excel table by period between two dates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter

I would like to filter a large Excel table by date in VBA. When I do it by hand with the "Between" filter, it works (see [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYo6a.png) and [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IZgD.png)).

If I run the "Record Macro" function at the same time, it also works and I get the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table5").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
  ">=15/09/2021", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=17/10/2021"
```

However, when I try to run the resulting macro, it filters out all records:

> *0 of 29725 records found*

Here is what I have tried:

1. Checked Stack Overflow Questions [#40820757](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820757/filtering-between-two-dates-in-excel-vba) and [#23132653](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132653/filter-between-dates-in-excel-vba).
2. Checked that the field was indeed in Date format: It is.
3. Went to the "Change Date and Time formats" menu in Windows and checked the local short date format in my system: "DD/MM/YYYY".
4. Tried the following code, which gave the same result:

```
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date

Date1 = CDate("15/09/2021")
Date2 = CDate("17/10/2021")

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table5").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
  ">=" & Date1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Date2
```

Do you have any idea of how I can troubleshoot this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the date format as in the code below.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Date1 = Format("15/09/2021", "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Date2 = Format("17/10/2021", "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
      ">=" & Date1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Date2
End Sub
```

Comment: This solved the problem, many thanks. To make this solution work, I also changed the type of Date1 and Date2 from Date to String.